# While Bayesian hypergraphs seem very interesting, won't they be even more data-hungry than Bayesian networks?

Tags: estimation, sample-size, causality, bayesian-network

There is a part of me that is absolutely enthused that someone has developed [Bayesian hypergraphs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.08372.pdf) and that it has [causal interpretations](https://why19.causalai.net/papers/SSS19_Paper_Upload_167.pdf) related to Judea Pearl's work. But with [Bayesian networks already being data-hungry](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.6862.pdf) in terms learning the correct structure, won't Bayesian hypergraphs be even more so?

Comment: Not necessarily. One could map hypergraph to a graph, so in practice they would bound to the same sample complexity as  standard Bayesian Networks.

Comment: That mapping argument sounds plausible to me. Would you mind sketching it out more formally/explicitly?

Comment: One would need to copy hyper-graph-edge and connect vertices, until each edge is identical to a graph-edge.

Comment: @Galen if you are interested in structural learning in more advanced PGMs like Bayesian Hypergraphs, checkout M. Javidian's work he recently published an article on learning LWF chain graphs

Comment: @KaanE. You're not talking about [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.08372.pdf) are you? That was in the OP.

Comment: *We propose a directed acyclic hypergraph framework for a probabilistic graphical model that
we call Bayesian hypergraphs.* - Javidian et al 2018

Comment: *Hence Bayesian hypergraphs can model much finer factorizations than
Bayesian networks or LWF chain graphs and provide simpler and more computationally efficient
procedures for factorizations and interventions*  - Javidian et al 2018

Comment: @KaanE. In any case, feel free to drop a link.